# In binary what is the result of 11 & ~10?

Tags: binary

i would ike to know what will be the result of the operation bellow.
In binary what is the result of 11 & ~10 ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are "11" and "10" decimal or binary? It also depends on what you mean with the ~ operation - a bitwise NOT?

If my assumptions are correct than you first have to invert bitwise '10' which will result in '01' and than do a bitwise AND: '11' & '01' to get '1'.

If in the future you aren't sure you can just try it out, for example with C# like this (or any other programming language you prefer):

```cs
var result = 0b11 & ~0b10;
Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
// Result: 1
```

You can even do that online without installing anything: https://ideone.com/9FZV9V

Comment: Thanks sir for your answer.